# How to handle the flow when a Network Exception is thrown

Tags: android, multithreading

I built an app and I need to handle Network Exceptions in many places. I want to know a way to do it.

In my `Activity` I have something like:

```
onCreate {
   ...
   fetchData(); // Needs Internet
   processData();
   showData();
}
```

In the `fetchData()` method, it might not fetch it because there's no connectivity or poor signal. In this case, I would show an `AlertDialog` and tell the user there was a network issue, and when he clicks `Ok` it would try to fetch it again.

The problem is that this thread would run `fetchData()`, build and show the `Dialog`, but it would keep running the `processData()` and so on. This method `fetchData()` is called two different places in my app, so the ideal would be to stop this thread until it tries again and load the data. What logic can I use here?

I know it might be a simple question, but I'm stuck on it and I don't know any patterns to apply. Should I propagate this error and handle it in the calls to `fetchData()`, or is there a way to stop this thread until the data is loaded?

**EDIT:** `fetchData()` **is** working and it runs a background thread that downloads the data, and wait it to finish to return the response or just null. So far, if there's an error I just get null and it logs me the network error. I want to know how to handle this and keep the flow

Comment: use try and catch block to handle errors and exceptions.

Comment: I'm trying to handle the FLOW, not merely the exception

Comment: add your flow in the try block, if there is no exception or error it continues to run line by line. But if an error or exception occurs it jumps to catch block and does not execute the remaining lines of code. To the user show some toast or alert dialog to notify that an error or exception occurs....

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code with this:

```
onCreate {
   ...
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask()
     {
             @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
            {
                 Try{
                     fetchData();} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
     }
             processData();
            showData();
    }
```

Comment: The question is not about doing networking it in background, is how to handle if there's an error in background and keep doing things in the same order

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain in my question that what I needed was a logic to handle the flow of my app. I was not asking how to catch an Exception.

What I ended up doing was basically a chain where a method calls the next one(s):

```
onCreate {
    ...
    fetchData(); // Needs Internet
}

fetchData() {
    if (data was fetched) {
        processFetchedData();
    }
    else { // Problem fetching data
        // Alerts user with AlertDialog and ask him to try again, then call fetchData() itself
    }
}

processFetchedData() {
    processData();
    showData();
}
```

Basically, I used recursion to call the method itself when there's an error. And the subsequent methods that need this one to be executed are called from it when the task was successful.

Hope this helps someone.